# Twisted forms of a free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring an let $A$ and $B$ be two $R$-algebras. If $S$ is faithfully flat over $R$ then we say that $A$ is a $S$-twisted form of $B$ if $A\otimes_R S$ and $B\otimes_R S$ are isomorphic as $S$-algebras.

Now, if $F$ is a free $R$-module, $ rank R=n$, and $S$ is a commutative algebra which is faithfully flat over the commutative and unitary ring $R$, could you prove that a $R$-module $P$ is a $S$-twisted form of $F$ if and only if $P\otimes_R S$ is a free $S$-module of rank n?

Comment: You define the notion for algebras but then your question is about modules. If the definition of $S$-twisted forms for modules is what I think it is (simply replacing "algebra" by "module" in the defintion above), then the answer is obviously yes.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I meant! well, I cannot formalize a proof...

Comment: $F \otimes_R S \simeq S^n$, so it seems obvious to me. Are you sure you wrote the right statement that you want to prove?

Comment: Oh, yes! It was obvious! How could I be so silly!!!!! :) Sorry!